# How to duplicate image with workpath from one psd to another in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I make a clipping path on an image in photoshop and save the workpath and thereafter duplicate the image from one psd to another psd file, then only that specific image layer is duplicated to the other psd file, the workpath is not duplicated. Now if I copy the workpath from source psd and paste it to the destination path layer, the path is not aligned with the exported image (clipping path).

Is there any option in photoshop so that the image can be duplicated along with its workpath from one psd to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit convoluted, but works....

Original file:

- Select the `work path` via the **Path Selection** or **Direct Selection** Tool (White or Black arrow)
- Choose `Layer > New Fill Layer > Solid color..` (click `OK` then pick a color, any color - this is ultimately a temporary layer)
- Highlight the new vector shape layer which was just created *and* the pixel layer it aligns with and duplicate/drag these two layers to the new file.

New file:

- Highlight the `Color Fill` path in the **Paths Panel** and copy it by dragging it to the **copy icon** at the bottom of the panel.
- This should create a new `Path 1` path in the **Paths Panel**
- Drag the `Color Fill` path to the **trash icon** on the **Paths Panel** to remove it (this will also remove the vector shape layer associated with it.)

Now you can highlight and designate `Path 1` as a clipping path and it should still be aligned with the raster layer.

---

As far as I'm aware, there's no *direct* option to link a path with any raster layer (other than a vector mask). And the **Path Panel** offers no ability to copy/duplicate a path to another file, unlike layers.

**However,** you *can* drag a path from the **Path Panel** to another document and the path should remain in the same relative location:

[image]

**But** position is only really maintained if *both files are the **same dimensions*** If the two files are different dimensions, the path gets centered within the document when it's dropped. The centering of the path may or may not be an issue depending upon the files.